# Морфемный состав

Tags: орфография

*Жж-ён-ый* или *жжё-н- ый*?

Answer (score 1):

В Словообразовательном словаре русского языка А.Н. Тихонова в слове **жжёный** выделяются следующие морфемы: жж-ён(ый). В корне происходит чередование -жж-/-жиг-/-жг- (например, с**жиг**ать, **жг**учий), морфема -ён- является суффиксом, -ый -- окончание

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, правильным будет второй вариант, ибо в слова «жжение» корень «жже».
Вероятно, здесь аналогично. «жжё» — корень, «н» — суффикс и «ый» — окончание.

Comment: В слове "жжение" морфемный состав следующий: жж-ениj-е. Сравните: терпение, умение, ускорение и т.д. В существительных такого типа выделяется суффикс -ениj-.